# Изменить владельца и права на директорию внутри докер контейнера

Tags: docker

Есть `Dockerfile` с таким содержимым:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm
...
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
```

И файл docker-compose.yml:

```
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/logs/php-fpm:/var/www/html/storage/logs
```

После сборки и запуска командой `docker-compose up -d` все работает, но проблема в том что владельцем директории `/var/www/html` все равно является root, а не www-data. Как сделать, так чтобы владельцем был именно www-data?